# How to traverse react tree recursively and get states of the react elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use [react-children-utilities](https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities) to traverse react tree recursively like this:

```
import Children from 'react-children-utilities';
...

Children.deepForEach(window.rootNode, (child) => {
    if (child.props.key === '...') {
          //child.state === undefined
    }
});
```

What I need to do is accessing the state of the element, but I am not able to do so in the above code. If I understand this right: the problem is, `child` in the above code is a react element, not a react component. So, is there a way to get the state out of a react element?

otherwise, is there a way other than [react-children-utilities](https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities) to recursively traverse react tree and get states of a react component/element?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [react-children-utilities](https://github.com/fernandopasik/react-children-utilities). The problem you are describing I think it goes against the principles of **React** as the components do not expose their **state** to the parent components. If you need to get something from the child elements I suggest implement an event and pass a value from them.